# What turns following to __builtin__?

Tags: python, metaclass, built-in

I have following snippet and output

`with metaclass:`

```
def some(*args):
    return type(args)

__metaclass__ = some

class Foo:
   a = 'khkjh'


print Foo.__module__
```

Output: `__builtin__`

`without metaclass:`

```
class Foo:
   a = 'khkjh'

print Foo.__module__
```

Output: `__main__`

So,

What is `__builtin__`?

why or how metaclass is affecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__builtin__` is the module that provides all built-in functions, exceptions, etc.

You're getting this returned from `__module__` because the metaclass you're providing is essentially turning `Foo` into the `tuple` type:

```
>>> def some (*args):
...  return type(args)  # This returns <type 'tuple'>
...
>>> class Hmm(object):
...  __metaclass__ = some
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...  pass
... 
>>> print Hmm
<type 'tuple'>
>>> print Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> print tuple
<type 'tuple'>
>>> print tuple.__module__
__builtin__
```

As you can see `Hmm` is now the type `tuple`. The `tuple` type is provided by the `__builtin__` module, hence the output you're seeing.